# Blender particle system with video layer

Tags: particles

Very new to Blender...but I'm attempting to create animated rain ripples with just a texture layer. I have set up a video layer as a plane in Blender then plugged it through a particle system to display across a plane. The only thing I can't figure out is how I can randomize the playback of the video layer so that the ripples aren't all playing back in sync. I know you can offset frames for playback, but I need to randomize it for the particle system. Is this possible?[[image: ripples all in sync][1]]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid out of the box that is not possible. They all share the same material and therefore the same texture. If the texture is animated all of them will be in the same point of the animation.
Workarounds:

1. make 3-4 planes, add them to a group and instead of object in your particle emitter choose group and pick random. Then create 3-4 materials with the same image texture and offset them by n frames.
2. Use dynamic paint. It takes a little longer to bake, but you can actually use the result as a normal map, giving you much more realism. Or you can even bake the animation to vertices to get real displacement. Careful though for a large plane that could take a lot of vertices.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I actually don't need displacement for the ripples since it's so stylized, so I will try using the emitter with the grouped planes and multiple materials.